# GC_CONCURRENT freed

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Hi I am very new to java coding, I am currently making an app but the I ran into this problem:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1151K, 19% free 5594K/6868K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 86ms
```

I did some searching and found out I have to do Garbage Collecting, can someone tell me how garbage collection works. E.g When does an object become eligible for garbage collection and please tell me if there is a way to force it.

I used the Allocation Tracker and it said that []byte is allocated the most. Please help me I don't see my self progressing in programming if I don't solve it.

Edit:Can Someone help me with my GC_CONCURRENT error then, I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: you should not care about garbage collection at your point: it's done for you. Once you run into OutOfMemoryErrors you should start looking into it in more detail.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html - I don't see you progressing without knowing how to research a topic.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer actually it's better to know main Android memory management principle. It definitely would help avoid memory leaks at least.

Comment: This looks like an informational message.  If you have a error stopping you progressing, this is not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has automatic garbage collection. You don't need to manage it but save application high performance.

Sometimes you can use `finalize()` - method helps in garbage collection.

Each time an object is created in Java, it goes into the area of memory known as heap. The Java heap is called
the garbage collectable heap. The garbage collection cannot be forced. The garbage collector runs in low
memory situations. When it runs, it releases the memory allocated by an unreachable object. The garbage
collector runs on a low priority daemon (i.e. background) thread. You can nicely ask the garbage collector to
collect garbage by calling `System.gc()` but **you can’t force it**.

Comment: Using `finalize()` usually makes the job **harder** for the garbage collector. You should **only** use it when absolutely necessary (mostly for resources external to the JVM and even then it can often be avoided).

Comment: yep, actually I never used it, no needed

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection is not something you have to *worry* about generally, but you should know it's happening.
There's a thread (the garbage collector) constantly monitoring your application. An object becomes eligible when there are no references left to it. 
Don't worry about forcing garbage collection, worry about not leaving references to objects your don't need around. Set a reference to null.

If you're getting memory errors it's probably because you're handling gigantic amounts of data or have some kind of infinite recusion problem.

Comment: Good answer *but* you're mixing some implementation-specific details in there (specifically that the garbage collector is a thread). Just leave that out, as it may or may not be true on any given implementation (and it generally doesn't matter!).

Answer (score -5):

```
System.gc();
```

will force garbage collection

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html
Javadoc says

```
static void gc() 
          Runs the garbage collector.
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for `gc()`? Don't read the first line of the javadoc, read all of it.

Comment: *will force garbage collection* ... no, it won't.

Comment: re: your edit; read the entire paragraph. After which you may want to research further on how that actually works and what "suggests" means in that context.